# Debugging applications with large linked libraries takes a lot of time

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm using some of the LLVM-Project libraries which results in a file the size of 180MBs when it gets linked. This causes a problem of delay every time I'm trying to debug the application which is waiting at least around 40 to 52 seconds to link those large libraries. I have an NVME M.2 SSD which is really fast at liking but giving that it links lots of large libraries it takes a lot of time which can be tedious having to wait 40 seconds every time wanting to debug the program. I'm using Visual Studio 2019, Is there any existing setting that would optimize link time?

Comment: Have you tried dynamic linkage? Seems llvm uses static linkage by default.

Comment: Using Dynamic link libraries? Like compiling LLVM to spit out dynamic libraries?

Comment: I think it could be a choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alex Reinking said, LLVM Dynamic linking isn't supported on Windows but there is a way around it.
Following this [link](https://github.com/CRogers/LLVM-Windows-Binaries/blob/master/compiling.md)
I was successful to enable dynamic linking on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately LLVM does not support dynamic linking on Windows. Since static linking is the only supported scenario on Windows, I'm afraid the answer to your question is "no", assuming you're linking the exact set of LLVM libraries you need to debug (maybe you don't need every backend, for example).

See the docs here: https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html

> `LLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB:BOOL`
>
> If enabled, the target for building the `libLLVM` shared library is added. This library contains all of LLVM's components in a single shared library. Defaults to OFF. This cannot be used in conjunction with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS. Tools will only be linked to the `libLLVM` shared library if `LLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB` is also ON. The components in the library can be customised by setting `LLVM_DYLIB_COMPONENTS` to a list of the desired components. **This option is not available on Windows.**

Emphasis mine.